# Is ActionListener an example of Delegation pattern?

Tags: java, design-patterns, awt, actionlistener

In my college days, I never realized  what patterns were there in the Java API.
Now at work I came across Delegation pattern in Objective C n Cocoa on iOS where one screen sets itself as a delegate on coming screen so that that screen can pass some message to that delegate and it can take some action when it comes back to the previous screen.

I realize that I use to do something similar with when I used to pass "this" as as ActionListener [by implementing the interface] to a JButton and it would automatically call actionPerformed implemented by me in this class and thus I could change any instance data in my JFrame class.

So Is ActionListener an example of Delegate If I am correct ?

**EDIT: As correctly mentioned below, It is Observer pattern. We dont set ActionListener we add one. Thus there can be many Listeners to that action.**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ActionListener` is an example of the [observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern). You register observers (or listeners) on a component that get called when a specific event occurs.

Comment: That's correct. Before I deleted my post I mentioned it's command pattern. It is not. Action is, but not ActionListener.

Comment: But I can only set one observer per JButton. not many.
We have setActionListener method not addActionListener to add many.

Comment: my JButtons have addActionListener methods. Shame yours are limited.

Comment: @Amogh: I'm not sure where you're looking. `JButton` extends `AbstractButton` which has an `addActionListener` method: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#addActionListener%28java.awt.event.ActionListener%29

Comment: I am sorry, My mistake. I remembered it wrongly. It is indeed Observer  pattern.

Comment: @MeBigFatGuy: Actually My JButtons also had the method. Shame on me.. I forgot :P !